# Real and imaginary part of $ (1-i\sqrt{3})^6$

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

i am a bit stuck here.

As the title says i try to find out how to write complex numbers like for example$$ (1-i\sqrt{3})^6$$ in the normal representation$$ z = x + i*y$$
I already found out that the polar representation of complex numbers will come in handy here, but i can't make the conclusion at the moment.

How can i get from here to the polar representation? How do i get the real and imaginary part from the polar representation? If you have a hint, can you please just leave a quick post here, thanks.

Comment: What about de Moivre ? It should be simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modulus of $1-i\sqrt{3}$ is $\sqrt{1+3}=2$, so you can write
$$
1-i\sqrt{3}=2\left(\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)
=
2(\cos(-\pi/3)+i\sin(-\pi/3))
$$
Can you compute the sixth power, now?

Comment: I thought that nothing was faster than light. I was wrong ! You are.

Comment: @Timbuc Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Ah, okay! Well, if i leave out the factor 2 it is $cos(2*-\pi) + i * sin(2*-\pi)$ but how can i put the factor two in de moivres formula?

Comment: @FalcoWinkler $\bigl(r(\cos\varphi+i\sin\varphi)\bigr)^n=r^n(\cos \varphi+i\sin \varphi)^n=r^n(\cos n\varphi+i\sin n\varphi)$

Comment: Allright! Thanks that helped me out.

Answer (score 4):

we know $$w=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\Longrightarrow w^2+w+1=0\Longrightarrow w^3=1$$
so
$$(1-i\sqrt{3})^6=(\sqrt{3}i-1)^6=2^6\cdot\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}i-1}{2}\right)^6=2^6w^6=2^6\cdot 1^2=64$$

Comment: I thought that nothing was faster than light. I was wrong ! You are.

Comment: Hello,which wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong, @math110...but was it really necessary to give the complete, detailed final answer?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$1-i\sqrt3=2e^{-\frac{\pi i}3}\implies (1-i\sqrt3)^6=\left(2e^{-\frac{\pi i}3}\right)^6=\ldots$$
**Another forceful way**:

$$(1-i\sqrt3)(1-i\sqrt3)=-2-2\sqrt3\,i=-2(1+\sqrt3\,i)\implies $$

$$(1-\sqrt3\,i)^3=-2(1+\sqrt3\,i)(1-\sqrt3\,i)=-2\cdot4=-8\implies$$

$$(1-\sqrt3\,i)^6=\left((1-\sqrt3\,i)^3\right)^2=\ldots$$

Comment: I thought that nothing was faster than light. I was wrong ! You are.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Hehe...well, it was a rather short answer, Claude. Even now that I added some stuff it still is pretty short.